# How to merge two RenderTargetBitmap instances?

Tags: wpf, rendertargetbitmap

Hey, guys.
I need to merge two RenderTargetBitmaps of the same size into one.
How would I do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wyh not create a third RenderTargetBitmap and render in this the both images you created with your RenderTargetBitmap_a and RenderTargetBitmap_b.

Something like:

```
...

Image imgA = new Image(){Source=renderTargetBitmapA};
Image imgB = new Image(){Source=renderTargetBitmapB};

renderTargetBitmapDest.Render(imgA);
renderTargetBitmapDest.Render(imgB);

...
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a nice idea. But still looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: While there is no better solution proposed, I mark your message as an answer.